# jCarousel for continous moving of images on mousepress

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, jcarousel

I am using [jCarousel](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/)  jquery slider.This is my code...

```
jQuery("#slide-pager").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: "#slide-pager_next",
    btnPrev: "#slide-pager_prev",
    circular: false,
    mouseWheel: true,
    visible:9
});
```

This works fine for me but this works when I click on **prev** and **next** button and displays one by one image but I want that when mouse keep pressed then images moves automatically continuously.

Hope you are getting my point.

Please help...
Thanks!